# complaints of glue length "mu"; amsart; list of definitions

Tags: table-of-contents, theorems, amsart

So I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% Modifications to amsart ToC-related macros...
\makeatletter
\let\old@tocline\@tocline
\let\section@tocline\@tocline

% Insert a dotted ToC-line for \subsection and \subsubsection only
\newcommand{\subsection@dotsep}{4.5}
\newcommand{\subsubsection@dotsep}{4.5}
\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \subsection@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \subsection@dotsep mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak}{}{}
\let\subsection@tocline\@tocline
\let\@tocline\old@tocline

\patchcmd{\@tocline}
  {\hfil}
  {\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \subsubsection@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \subsubsection@dotsep mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak}{}{}
\let\subsubsection@tocline\@tocline
\let\@tocline\old@tocline

\let\old@l@subsection\l@subsection
\let\old@l@subsubsection\l@subsubsection

\def\@tocwriteb#1#2#3{%
  \begingroup
    \@xp\def\csname #2@tocline\endcsname##1##2##3##4##5##6{%
      \ifnum##1>\c@tocdepth
      \else \sbox\z@{##5\let\indentlabel\@tochangmeasure##6}\fi}%
    \csname l@#2\endcsname{#1{\csname#2name\endcsname}{\@secnumber}{}}%
  \endgroup
  \addcontentsline{toc}{#2}%
    {\protect#1{\csname#2name\endcsname}{\@secnumber}{#3}}}%

% Handle section-specific indentation and number width of ToC-related entries
\newlength{\@tocsectionindent}
\newlength{\@tocsubsectionindent}
\newlength{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}
\newlength{\@tocsectionnumwidth}
\newlength{\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}
\newlength{\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth}
\newcommand{\settocsectionnumwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsectionnumwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionnumwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionnumwidth}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsectionindent}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsectionindent}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionindent}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsectionindent}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionindent}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}{#1}}

% Handle section-specific formatting and vertical skip of ToC-related entries
% \@tocline{<level>}{<vspace>}{<indent>}{<numberwidth>}{<extra>}{<text>}{<pagenum>}
\renewcommand{\l@section}{\section@tocline{1}{\@tocsectionvskip}{\@tocsectionindent}{\@tocsectionnumwidth}{\@tocsectionformat}}%
\renewcommand{\l@subsection}{\subsection@tocline{1}{\@tocsubsectionvskip}{\@tocsubsectionindent}{\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}{\@tocsubsectionformat}}%
\renewcommand{\l@subsubsection}{\subsubsection@tocline{1}{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}{\@tocsubsubsectionindent}{\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth}{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}}%
\newcommand{\@tocsectionformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsectionformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}{}
\expandafter\def\csname toc@1format\endcsname{\@tocsectionformat}
\expandafter\def\csname toc@2format\endcsname{\@tocsubsectionformat}
\expandafter\def\csname toc@3format\endcsname{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}
\newcommand{\settocsectionformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsectionformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsectionformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionformat}{#1}}
\newlength{\@tocsectionvskip}
\newcommand{\settocsectionvskip}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsectionvskip}{#1}}
\newlength{\@tocsubsectionvskip}
\newcommand{\settocsubsectionvskip}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsectionvskip}{#1}}
\newlength{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}
\newcommand{\settocsubsubsectionvskip}[1]{\setlength{\@tocsubsubsectionvskip}{#1}}

% Adjust section-specific ToC-related macros to have a fixed-width numbering framework
\patchcmd{\tocsection}{\indentlabel}{\makebox[\@tocsectionnumwidth][l]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tocsubsection}{\indentlabel}{\makebox[\@tocsubsectionnumwidth][l]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\tocsubsubsection}{\indentlabel}{\makebox[\@tocsubsubsectionnumwidth][l]}{}{}

% Allow for section-specific page numbering format of ToC-related entries
\newcommand{\@sectypepnumformat}{}
\renewcommand{\contentsline}[1]{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\@sectypepnumformat\csname @toc#1pnumformat\endcsname%
  \csname l@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@tocsectionpnumformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsectionpnumformat}{}
\newcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionpnumformat}{}
\newcommand{\setsectionpnumformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsectionpnumformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setsubsectionpnumformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsectionpnumformat}{#1}}
\newcommand{\setsubsubsectionpnumformat}[1]{\renewcommand{\@tocsubsubsectionpnumformat}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\@tocpagenum}[1]{%
  \hfill {\mdseries\@sectypepnumformat #1}}

% Small correction to Appendix, since it's still a \section which should be handled differently
\let\oldappendix\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendix}{%
  \leavevmode\oldappendix%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \protect\settowidth{\protect\@tocsectionnumwidth}{\protect\@tocsectionformat\sectionname\space}%
    \protect\addtolength{\protect\@tocsectionnumwidth}{2em}}%
}
\makeatother

% #1 (default is as required)

% #2

% #3
\makeatletter
\settocsectionnumwidth{2em}
\settocsubsectionnumwidth{2.5em}
\settocsubsubsectionnumwidth{3em}
\settocsectionindent{1pc}%
\settocsubsectionindent{\dimexpr\@tocsectionindent+\@tocsectionnumwidth}%
\settocsubsubsectionindent{\dimexpr\@tocsubsectionindent+\@tocsubsectionnumwidth}%
\makeatother

% #4 & #5
\settocsectionvskip{10pt}
\settocsubsectionvskip{0pt}
\settocsubsubsectionvskip{0pt}

% #6 & #7
% See #3

% #8
\renewcommand{\contentsnamefont}{\bfseries\Large}

% #9
\settocsectionformat{\bfseries}
\settocsubsectionformat{\mdseries}
\settocsubsubsectionformat{\mdseries}
\setsectionpnumformat{\bfseries}
\setsubsectionpnumformat{\mdseries}
\setsubsubsectionpnumformat{\mdseries}

% #10
% Insert the following command inside your text where you want the ToC to have a page break
\newcommand{\tocpagebreak}{\leavevmode\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\clearpage}}

% #11
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{%
  \vspace*{-\linespacing}% Default gap to top of CONTENTS is \linespacing.
  \oldtableofcontents}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%  PROBLEM AREA   %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
 %AMSART STUFF

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{xca}[theorem]{Exercise}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,%
    citecolor=black,%
    filecolor=black,%
    linkcolor=black,%
    urlcolor=black
}

% renew \contentsline for toc to include hypertarget
\let\oldcontentsline\contentsline%
\renewcommand\contentsline[4]{%
\hypertarget{toc#4}{}%
\oldcontentsline{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}}

% renew \section to link to the toc
\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\Large\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsection.\thesection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

% renew \subsection to link to the toc
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\bf}
{{\thesection} \hyperlink{tocsubsection.\thesubsection}{#1}}
{1pc}
{}

\begin{document}

\title{Report fom}

%    Information for first author
\author{Brn}
%    Address of record for the research reported here
\address{6G1}
%    Current address

\email{safds@fds.ca}
%    \thanks will become a 1st page footnote.
\thanks{The author was supported bnd the Department.}

%    General info
%\subjclass[2000]{Primary 54C40, 14E20; Secondary 46E25, 20C20}

\date{\today.}

%\dedicatory{This paper is dedicated to my advisor.}

\keywords{Differ??}

\begin{abstract}
This paper is 
\end{abstract}

\maketitle


\tableofcontents

%\listoftheorems

\section{This is a numbered first-level section head}
This is an example of a numbered first-level heading.

\begin{theorem}
stuff
\end{theorem}

\subsection{This is a numbered second-level section head}
This is an example of a numbered second-level heading.

\section{This fasfdasfdsais a numbered first-level section head}
This is an example of a numbered first-level heading.

\subsection*{This is an unnumbered second-level section head}
This is an example of an unnumbered second-level heading.

\end{document}
```

and whenever I try to write out a list of theorems, or definitions it complains of a glue length "mu"... I've traced it to maybe the

```
% Insert a dotted ToC-line for \subsection and \subsubsection only
```

at the 4th item down, but I don't know why theorems would be treated as either sub or subsubsections. The definitions and theorems etc show up fine in the body but when I implement their printing, *i.e.*

```
\listtheorems (or is it \listoftheorems ?)
```

I get this glue length error.

As an aside note, when is it proper to use `ntheorem`, `amsthm`, etc ?

Comment: Each package for theorems provides some functionally that may be of interest to the user, and there exists some overlap. However, it ultimately lies with the user whether one package provide more functionality they're after than another. Note though that some theorem package are incompatible with others. Since you're using and AMS-related document class - `amsart` - it's best to stick to the AMS-related theorem package ([`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm)).

Comment: if you are using `amsart`, the `amsthm` facilities are incorporated (there are a few small differences from the standalone version of `amsthm`).  and to the best of my knowledge, no other theorem packages are compatible with the ams document classes; `ntheorem` certainly isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the definition of `\@dotsep` to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@dotsep{4.5}
\makeatother
```

The above definition is similar to the other sectional units dot separations, which originally was taken from one of the default document classes (see, for example, [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls)).

Comment: That's a complicated looking file... :)

Comment: @nate: It comes close to your not-so-minimal example.